# nested record can't validate because its nested belongs_to doesn't save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-attributes, belongs-to

I'm trying to create a nested child and grandchild record.  The child belongs_to both the parent and the grandchild.  The child won't validates_presence_of the grandchild because it hasn't been saved yet.

I'm using Rails 2.3.11, Formtastic, InheritedResources, and Haml, and everything else seems to work correctly - for example, validation errors on the grandchild populate properly in the parent form, and the invalid values are remembered and presented to the user. The parent model doesn't even try to update unless everything is valid, just as it should be.

My code is something like this, though in a different problem domain:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meetings, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :meetings
end

class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :task
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :task
  validates_presence_of :task_id, :project_id
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meetings, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

The Project ALWAYS exists already, and may already have Meetings that we don't want to see. Tasks may belong to other Projects through other Meetings, but in this case, the Task and Meeting are ALWAYS new.

In the controller, I build a blank record only on the new action

```
@project.meetings.build
```

and save the data like this:

```
@project.update_attributes(params[:project])
```

and in the view

```
- semantic_form_for @project do |f|
  - f.semantic_fields_for :meetings do |m|
    - next unless m.object.new_record?
    = m.semantic_errors :task_id
    - m.object.build_task unless i.object.task
    - m.semantic_fields_for :task do |t|
      - f.inputs do
        = t.input :task_field
        = m.input :meeting_field
```

When I try to save the form, I get a validation error of "Task can't be blank."  Well, sure, the Task hasn't been saved yet, I'm trying to validate, and I don't have an ID for it.

Is there a simple and elegant way to make sure that the grandchild record (Task) gets built before the child record?

I've tried something like this in the Meeting model:

```
before_validation_on_create do |meeting|
  meeting.task.save if meeting.task.valid?
end
```

and that seems to save the Task, but the Meeting still doesn't get the right ID.  Same error, but the Task record gets created.

I've also tried this:

```
before_validation_on_create do |meeting|
  new_task = meeting.task.save if meeting.task.valid?
  meeting.task = new_task
end
```

Which has the strange behaviour of raising ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound "Couldn't find Task with ID=XX for Meeting with ID=" - which I sort of get, but seems like a red herring.

I also tried adding :inverse_of to all the relationships and validating :task instead of :task_id.  The latter, oddly, fails but seems to give no error message.

My actual goal here is to create more than one Task, each with an initial Meeting on a previously selected Project... so I could take another approach with my problem - I could do something simple and ugly in the controller, or create the first Meeting in an after_create on the Project.  But this is so pretty and soooo close to working.  The fact that I'm getting proper validation errors on :task_field and :meeting_field implies that I'm on the right track.

I see what the problem is, but not how to solve it: I suspect I'm missing something obvious.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution, based on one of the similar questions out there, but the short of it is "rails 2.3 doesn't seem to be very good at this."  I think I can put the answer in a more succinct way than any of the other answers I've seen.

What you do is you skip the validation of the :task_id, but only if task is valid!  Most of the other answers I've seen use a proc, but I think it's more readable using delegate, like this:

```
delegate :valid?, :to => :task, :prefix => true, :allow_nil => true
validates_presence_of :task_id, :unless => :task_valid?
```

I also had another problem hidden under the waterline - in the case, the "Project" is actually a special sort of record that I wanted to protect, which has a validation that (intentionally) fails only for this special record, and I also set readonly? to true for the special record.

Even though I'm not actually *changing* that special record, it still needs to validate and can't be readonly to update children through it.  For some reason, I wasn't seeing the error message for that validation.  To solve that, I made the validation on the Project only applicable :on => :create, and I took out the readonly? thing.

But the general solution is "don't validate presence of the unbuilt belongs_to object if the object itself is valid."  Nil is never valid, therefore the validation still works if you just have an object_id.

*(Please don't vote down a sincere question unless you have an answer or a link to one.  I'm aware the question has been asked by others in other ways, I read many of those other questions, none seemed to be precisely the same problem, and I had not found a solution.)*